# Hibernate logging native sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j2

I need to log all full queries (with parameters) in Hibernate 5.
My build.gradle (dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:1.7.8'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.5.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.38'
}
```

My log4j2-test.properties:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
# basic log level for all messages
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

But Hibernate don't want to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I use the XML configuration format and this works for me.

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="main_appender"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="main_appender"/>
</Logger>
```

My guess for how it translates is to have `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies are slightly wrong.

Please remove `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` (this is for the old Log4j 1) and add `org.apache.logging.log4j:slf4j-impl`.

Comment: That and set `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j` in the command line or call `System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");` before Hibernate is initialized.